# OpenGL ES 2 squeeze distortion filter like photobooth app

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I'm tryng to code a squeeze effect like the one in photobooth ios or osx app; I'm new to shaders, but I was able to implement GPUImage library and tweek some shaders; however all that I was able to obtain is a spherical distortion, and the final result is a bit different from what I would like to achieve.

here is some code I modded from #import "GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter.h"

in particular I was using this code

```
    NSString *const kGPUImageBulgeDistortionFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
    (
     varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

     uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

     uniform highp vec2 center;
     uniform highp float radius;
     uniform highp float scale;

     void main()
     {
         highp vec2 textureCoordinateToUse = textureCoordinate;
         highp float dist = distance(center, textureCoordinate);
         highp float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264;//stone added
         textureCoordinateToUse -= center;
        textureCoordinateToUse.x = 0.5+textureCoordinateToUse.x*cos(textureCoordinateToUse.x*PI/radius)*scale;
         textureCoordinateToUse.y = 0.5 + textureCoordinateToUse.y*cos(textureCoordinateToUse.y*PI/radius)*scale;


         gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinateToUse );

     }
    );
```

This code is using cos and sin and PI so it's definitely in the spherical range; any hint to make it more planar, with a tiny unstretched part in the middle will be a great help !